# How to Recursively Simulate a Random Walk? No Loops (Python)

Tags: python, recursion, simulation, random-walk

Python Question

I have a function for 1 random step:

```
def random_step(): 
    """ chooses a random step (-1 or 1) and returns it.
        inputs: none! However, make sure to use parens when calling it.
            For example: ramdom_step()
    """
    return random.choice([-1, 1])
```

And I need to call it in this function I am writing:

`rw_outcome( start, numsteps )`, that takes two inputs:

- `start`, an integer that represents the starting position of the sleepwalker
- `numsteps`, a positive int that represents the # of random steps to take from the starting position

It should simulate a random walk consisting of `numsteps` random steps whose sizes are determined using calls to `random_step()`, but I keep returning the same starting position.

An example of what it should return with print('start is', start):

```
>>> rw_outcome(40, 4)
start is 40
start is 41
start is 42
start is 41
start is 42
42
```

What I have so far:

```
def rw_outcome(start, numsteps):
    print('start is', start)
    if start + (numsteps*random_step()) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return rw_outcome(start,numsteps+1)
```

**Is it possible to write with recursion?**

Comment: Is it a problem with the base case? I have not read that I apologize.

Comment: It's a problem with your algorithm, or rather missing data. You need one more piece of data that indicates when a location is already visited.

Comment: @EvanPorter, is there any particular reason you don't want to use loops here?

Comment: @wnnmaw, I wrote it with loops very easily, but I got stuck on recursion after a colleague told me I couldn't do it. :'(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a couple of errors in your code. Try this:

```
def rw_outcome(start, numsteps):
print('start is', start)
if numsteps == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return rw_outcome(start+random_step(),numsteps-1)
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def random_step(nsteps=1):
    if nsteps>0:
        return random_step(nsteps-1)+random.choice([-1, 1])
    else:
        return 0

def rw_outcome(start, numsteps):
    return start+random_step(numsteps)
```